# Reload style in component

Tags: angular, angular5

I did not find my answer anywhere.
My project is divided in an API backend and an Angular Frontend.

I have the style of my project stored in a database, my backend convert it to a css file that I import in an angular component that I called "style".

Here's my style.component.ts

```ts
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

import { StyleService } from '../_services/style.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-style',
  template: ``,
  styleUrls: ['./style.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class StyleComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Here's my style.component.css

```css
@import url('http://192.168.100.10:3802/styles?css');
```

I would like to refresh this component thus the style is reloaded.
I tested to

```html
<app-style *ngIf="displayTheme"></app-style>
```

and when I want to refresh I get `displayTheme` to false then again to true thanks to a subject but it does nothing

Have you an idea ?

Comment: Where does `displayTheme` comes from? What's the logic behind this to determine `true` or `false`?

Comment: <app-style *ngIf="displayTheme"></app-style> is located in app.component.html, and I have in my app.component.ts `this.styleService.reloadThemeSubject.subscribe(() => {
      this.displayTheme = false;
      this.displayTheme = true;
    });`

Comment: When I add console.log('test') to this.styleService.reloadThemeSubject.subscribe, I see 'test' correctly when I save the style

Comment: `this.displayTheme = false; this.displayTheme = true;` exactly what is this suppose to achieve? It will always be true. You're just re assigning the variable with no purpose here... You should be setting the value to `true` on the complete callback.

Comment: Sorry, I wan't really clear. By default this.displayTheme is set to true. I thought I could reload my component by setting it to false then setting it again to true. What do you mean by "on the complete callback ?". Thanks for you answers :)

Comment: `subscribe` have 3 callbacks, `next`, `error` and `complete`. See some snippets, https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/callbacks.md